# Make a SBT task depends on an other one

Tags: sbt

I tried the following:

```
update := update.dependsOn(myTask)
```

But it runs myTask in parallel of update where myTask is needed to be finished before update starts.

I then tried the following that doesn't work at all:

```
update := myTask.runBefore(update).value
```

Any idea?

Cheers

Comment: myTask will not run in parallel with update if that dependsOn is set. are you sure you're depending from the correct update?

Comment: You are right @pfn. I am in a multi project so this key is defined on the root. Now that I defined it in the commons settings it execute it for every projects :( any idea about how to make it execute only once before the update?

Comment: Define myTask on the root project and then dependsOn(myTask in root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `myTask` was defined after the `dependsOn` or `runBefore` declaration and it seems to not be able to resolve it.

So declaring the tasks before solves the issue.